# Cylinderial Shells:Volume of a bounded Region

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, volume

I have to find the volume of the bounded region by the following functions:

> $$y=\frac{1}{x^3}$$
>   $$y=0$$
>   $$x=1$$
>   $$x=2$$
>   $$\mathbf{Revolving\ around\ the \ axis:}$$
>   $$x=-1$$

The method that one has to use is cylindrical shells, but if you could do it both methods slicing, and cylindrical.

I have this integral for cylindrical shells is:

$$V=2\pi \int_\limits{1}^{2}((x+1)(\frac{1}{x^3}))dx$$

But I did it using slicing as well which lead me to this integral:

$$V=\pi \int_\limits{\frac{1}{8}}^{1}((\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{y}}+1)^2-1^2)dy$$

Would it be possible, being that I know they should be equal the displacing of the axis of revolution is being quite trouble some, could you go in detail to how the axis is impacting both?

Comment: using slicing: should be $-2^2$ and not $-1^2$. Also add the volume of the region corresponding to $y$ between $0$ and $1/8$

Comment: @Lozenges How about for cylindrical shells?

Comment: Cylindrical looks ok